# sqlalchemy JSON query rows without a specific key (Key existence)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When using sqlalchemy with postgresql, I have the following table and data:

```
 id |   data   
----+----------
  1 | {}
  2 | {"a": 1}
(2 rows)
```

How do I find row(s) that does not have a key. e.g. "a" or data["a"]?

```
Give me all objects that does not have the key a.
 id |   data   
----+----------
  1 | {}
(1 row)
```

---

```
self.session.query(Json_test).filter(???)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the column type is `jsonb` you can use [`has_key`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB):

```
session.query(Json_test).filter(sqlalchemy.not_(Json_test.data.has_key('a')))
```

For both `json` and `jsonb` types this should work:

```
session.query(Json_test).filter(Json_test.data.op('->')('a')==None)
```

Comment: .has_key is now deprecated... i used a variation on your second answer: `not_(Json_test.data.op('?')('a')`

Comment: @nihilok - You are confusing [SQLAlchemy has_key()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.has_key) with [dict.has_key()](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dicts.html). The first is OK, the second was removed in Python3.