# sqlalchemy get json value by a dynamic key, which is a column value

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlalchemy model with field *concurrent_tasks_limits*, which is a postgresql JSON. Example value: {"RELAX": 3, "FAST": 3}. I also have a field *current_mode*, which is a string. I need to get a value from *concurrent_tasks_limits* by key, which is a  *current_mode* in the same row.

I tried to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
class MJAccounts(Base, PrettyRepr):
    __tablename__ = "mj_accounts"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    token: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)  # account token
    account_plan: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Enum(AccountPlan))
    current_mode: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        Enum(GenerationMode), default=GenerationMode.FAST
    )
    concurrent_tasks_limits = mapped_column(PG_JSON)
    
    @classmethod
    async def get_free_accounts(cls, session: AsyncSession):
        statement = select(MJAccounts).where(
            await MJAccounts.count_current_tasks(session)
            < MJAccounts.concurrent_tasks_limits[MJAccounts.current_mode]
        )

        return (await session.execute(statement)).scalars().all()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39928463/5320906) answer your question (if you negate the negation)?